# Drupal Smtp Config | Disabled fields are overridden in site-specific configuration file

Tags: drupal, smtp

When i trying to test email in smtp i'm getting this error **Disabled fields are overridden in site-specific configuration file.** Can anyone please help

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do. It seems this is an warning and not an error. Are you using SMTP module? Then there is an existing issue here: https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp/issues/2826189

Answer (score 0):

Try this once How to Use Google SMTP Server
https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-use-free-google-smtp-server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).